# JSP with Apache/2.2.17 (Ubuntu)

Tags: apache, jsp, ubuntu

I'm running a Ubuntu Sever with Apache/2.2.17.  I can't seem to run JSP I just get the source code in the browser.  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

> *What am I doing wrong?*

Expecting that [Apache HTTPD](http://httpd.apache.org/) magically supports JSP. It doesn't. You need [Apache Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org) instead.

#### See also:

- [Our JSP wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsp/info) - at the bottom you can find several tutorial links to get started properly.

Comment: apparently I'm a total noob.  I have both on the server, how do I chose to run JSP on tomcat rather than Apache

Comment: Forget HTTPD. Put JSPs in Tomcat's webapp deploy folder and then start Tomcat. Read its manual and go through some basic JSP tutorials. Our JSP wiki page refers an excellent one on coreservlets.com covering setting up Eclipse and Tomcat. If you still stucks, ask a new and more specific question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

1)get the mod_jk.so
2)include this in httpd.conf file
LoadModule jk_module modules/mod_jk.so
3)Then in virtual host section of httpd.conf

```
JkMount /test/*.jsp loadbalancer
```

Answer (score 0):

put your jsp file  in webapp dir in the tomcat directory. Run as localhost:8080/your.jsp from your browser. Also make sure tomcat is set properly by running localhsot:8080 form your browser.

Comment: Check your spelling of "localhost" on the second occurrence.